# Controllers in ASP.NET MVC multitentant app (without subdomains)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, multi-tenant

I've read several articles about how to use subdomains and custom routes for multitenant applications, but the project I'm working on requires only one domain. We're using the default membership provider, and storing the encrypted tenant ID in the cookie.

My question regards the controllers. We're currently building them so that the first item in every action retrieves the TenantID from the cookie, and then passes that into every Linq query. Is it safe to move that to the top of the controller class instead, so it only happens once per controller instance? Or does that cause potential data crossover if multiple users are accessing the same controller?

I found [this article](http://blog.tallan.com/2010/07/21/multi-tenant-architecture-via-dependency-injection-part-3/) which suggests that that's possible, but I want to be sure.

As an example, this is the current system:

```
public class ThisController : Controller
{
    private DBContext db = new ThisContext();

    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
        long tenantid = AuthUser.GetTenantID();
...
```

This is what we're considering:

```
public class ThisController : Controller
{
    private DBContext db = new ThisContext();

    private Int64 tenantid = AuthUser.GetTenantID();

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
...
```

My understanding of the default behavior is that a new instance of the controller class is created with every request, but I want to be sure that's correct before we proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes new instance of controller is indeed created by default for each request made to an mvc application. You can test it yourself by adding a constructor to the controller and doing Debug.WriteLine in the constructor.